# Can i create a user in a database with the same name as SQL USER?

Tags: sql

I have a user under SQL Server -> Security-> Logins as 'testuser'.

Can i create a database , TestDB and attempt to create a user in the TestDB with name 'testuser' Using sql code ?

Comment: Tag the DBMS you're using. Tag the client too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can set user 'testuser' user rights to access the database to some extent (owner, writer, reader, etc.) I assume it is MS SQL Server.